# Is it possible to limit the rows the formula sort() expends to in Google SpreadSheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to order a table and take only the first ten rows. To do it dynamically, I wish to use the formula [`=sort()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150); What I´m doing now is:

1)In one sheet (My Table) I have a table with 100+ rows.

2) I´ve create a second sheet(Sorted table), on this sheet I use the formula `=sort('My Table'!A2:B100,2,false)`. This creates a second table with the values sorted according to my criteria.

3) I use `=arrayformula('Sorted table!A2:b11)` on a third sheet (Results) to get the top 10 results.

I was wondering if possible to achieve the exact same result without the need of a second sheet. Something like =trim(sort('My Table'!A2:B100,2,false),10).

I know I can use a custom formula created in Google App Script. This is not my goal here. I want to know if there is a **NATIVE** function that does that.

Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function to achieve this. For example:

```
=QUERY('My Table'!A2:B100, "select A,B order by B asc limit 10")
```

It is pretty similar to SQL. You can read more about the possible syntax you can use under the [Google Visualization API Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) page.

Comment: How do you apply the query by using sum?
I want to show the top 5 producting agent over revenue